# Is key 'chord' functionality provided by Win32/.net?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, windows

Several MS apps support the concept of chords, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> , <kbd>Y</kbd> which means "holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>".

Is this a bespoke thing they (and other companies) implement, or is it built into any APIs? It would be nice to be able to set up event handlers or accelerators based on chords rather than write code to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Accelerators' support normal key presses plus any combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

For what you are asking for, I think you would need to process `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions using GetKeyAsyncState from which you can directly derive which keys are currently up and down. Tracking every WM_KEYUP/DOWN is not easy and most naive solutions have issues with multiple apps and multiple threads.

A possible solution would be to detect the 'easy' part of the combination with an accellerator (i.e. the ctrl-Y) and then check whether the other keys (i.e. X) are down in the handler.